# cordova-plugin-network-information produces ClassNotFoundException with MobileFirst V8.0

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

When building a Cordova application for MobileFirst Platform Foundation V8.0 in conjunction with the cordova-plugin-network-information plugin, a ClassNotFoundException is thrown when the app is started.

The product versions I'm running are as follows.  I've also seen this same error when using Ionic 2:

- cordova : 6.3.0
- ionic : 1.3.1
- ionic cli : 1.7.16
- cordova-plugin-mfp : 8.0
- cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore : 8.0

Here is how I reproduce the problem:

Create the ionic project

- ionic start testproject
- cd testproject

Add the plugins

- ionic plugins add cordova-plugin-mfp
- ionic plugins add cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore

Add the Android platform

- ionic platform add android

Run the app

- ionic run android

At this point there are no errors in the logs.  However, if you add the following plugin and run again:

- cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
- ionic run android

Then the following stacktrace is produced:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNetworkManager
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:324)
at java.lang.Class.forName (Class.java:285)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:490)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:170)
at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:123)
at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and APAR [PI68455](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI68455) has been created to address it.  A fix has been developed and will be released in the next [iFix on Fix Central](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other%20software/IBM%20MobileFirst%20Platform%20Foundation&release=8.0.0.0&platform=All&function=all).  I'll update this post as soon as the iFix is released.